# Delphi encoding with web service response

Tags: web-services, delphi, utf-8

I am using Delphi 10 Seattle and I'm having a problem with the xml response of a web service, It return rare character like  **ÃƒÂº**  when the expected value is **ú** or **á,é,í,ó**

I'm using the HTTPRIO component to call the webservice:

```
    vRequest_test:=uGetServiceSoap_test.GetServiceSoap(False,'',HR);
    vResponse:=vRequest_test.FECAESolr(vAuth,vSeg);
```

where HR is the HTTPRIO component. I get response XML  with the AfterExecute event:

```
procedure TSegElec.RIOAfterExecute(const MethodName: string;
  SOAPResponse: TStream);

begin
   SoapResponse.Position := 0;
   fXMLFResponse.LoadFromStream(SOAPResponse);

end;
```

where FXMLFresponse is a TString variable.

I have tried set encoding to utf-8 and also setting option variable to :

```
[soSendMultiRefObj,soTryAllSchema,**soUTF8InHeader**,soCacheMimeResponse,**soUTF8EncodeXML**]
```

But not result :(, when I call the WS with SoapUI tool it return the correct charater values.

Any idea that I can try?

Regards